# what does this line of code means???? (new in programming!)

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT p
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM SUPPLIER S
        WHERE S.SUPPL_CODE = p.SUPPL_CODE
      ) = 0;
```

Comment: You should review a good SQL tutorial, then come back when you have a more concrete question to ask.

Comment: u are my sql tutorial!!!!! @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this code is to get products that have no suppliers (or whose supplier does not exist).  That is, the count of suppliers for the product is `0`.

The better way to write the code would use `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SUPPLIER S WHERE S.SUPPL_CODE = p.SUPPL_CODE );
```

Why is this better?  In the aggregation version, the full count has to be calculated.  In this version, the subquery can stop at the first matching value.

Comment: HI can i modiffy the codes to  SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT p
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM SUPPLIER S
        WHERE S.SUPPL_CODE <> p.SUPPL_CODE
      ) ;               will it still work the same>>>> @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @WenXIANG1999 . . . Obviously, that is a different query and not what this question is about.